# getting xml element attribute value and set as html ul li list type

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

this is my xml file:-

```
<root>
  <child_1 entity_id = "1" value="Game" parent_id="0">
    <child_2 entity_id="2" value="Activities" parent_id="1">
      <child_3 entity_id="3" value="Physical1" parent_id="2">
        <child_6 entity_id="6" value="Cricket" parent_id="3">
          <child_7 entity_id="7" value="One Day" parent_id="6"/>
        </child_6>
      </child_3>
      <child_4 entity_id="4" value="Test1" parent_id="1">
        <child_8 entity_id="8" value="Test At Abc" parent_id="4"/>
      </child_4>
      <child_5 entity_id="5" value="Test2" parent_id="1">
        <child_9 entity_id="9" value="Test At Xyz" parent_id="5"/>
      </child_5>
    </child_2>
   <child_10 entity_id="10" value="Region" parent_id="1">
      <child_11 entity_id="11" value="ABC" parent_id="10">
        <child_12 entity_id="12" value="XYZ" parent_id="11">
          <child_13 entity_id="13" value="ABC123" parent_id="12"/>
        </child_12>
      </child_11>
  </child_10>
</child_1>
</root>
```

here i want to start getting element attribute value `Activities` `(child_2)`

and there child sub child value also.

and set in html format like `ul li`
look something like this:-

```
<ul>
  <li>Activity</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Physical</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Cricket</li>
      <ul>
        <li>One-Day</li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
    <li>Test2</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Test At Abc</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Test3</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Test At Xyz</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

i dont know xslt very well but i think its easy way to solve this.

any help well come.
thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will produce the output you described:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="item">
    <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
    </li>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="current()[*]" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*/*">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1] | node()[current()/ancestor::*[2]]" 
                           mode="item" />
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, the output you described is not legal HTML (`ul`s can't directly contain other `ul`s). This will produce valid HTML:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="item">
    <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="current()[*]" />
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*/*">
    <ul>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1] | node()[current()/ancestor::*[2]]" 
                            mode="item" />
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<ul>
  <li>Activities<ul>
      <li>Physical1<ul>
          <li>Cricket<ul>
              <li>One Day</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Test1<ul>
          <li>Test At Abc</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Test2<ul>
          <li>Test At Xyz</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Which renders as:

- Activities

  - Physical1

    - Cricket

      - One Day
  - Test1

    - Test At Abc
  - Test2

    - Test At Xyz

Comment: hey can its possible when click on there leaf node there text is display in div

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Could you open a separate question for that?

Comment: this is my question .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191951/set-click-event-on-leaf-node

Comment: here is little bit problem. if first stag  multiple level are given then its return all xml attribute. we want only child_2 and there child not there level element.

Comment: I've modified both of my answers above accordingly.

Comment: when over xslt creat li tag we are set in them last li `<li onclick="test()">`? its possible.