# set click event on leaf node

Tags: javascript, xslt

i have this type of html :-

```
<ul>
  <li>Activities<ul>
      <li>Physical1<ul>
          <li>Cricket<ul>
              <li>One Day</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Test1<ul>
          <li>Test At Abc</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Test2<ul>
          <li>Test At Xyz</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<br>
```

this is my full code to load xml file and xslt. and get the ul li list using xslt.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script>
        var xml = loadXMLDoc("abc.xml");
        var xsl = loadXMLDoc("a.xsl");

        function loadXMLDocActiveX(location) {
            var doc = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument");
            doc.async = false;
            doc.load(location);
            return doc;
        }

        function loadXMLDocOther(location) {
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.open("GET", location, false);
            xhttp.send("");
            return xhttp.responseXML;
        }

        function loadXMLDoc(dname) {
            if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                return loadXMLDocActiveX(dname);
            }
            else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                return loadXMLDocOther(dname);
            }
        }

        function transformActiveX(xml, xsl, target, selected) {
            var transform = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XSLTemplate");
            transform.stylesheet = xsl;
            var processor = transform.createProcessor();
            processor.input = xml;

            if (selected) {
                processor.addParameter("selected", selected);
            }

            processor.transform();
            target.innerHTML = processor.output;
        }

        function transformOther(xml, xsl, target, selected) {
            var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
            xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);

            if (selected) {
                xsltProcessor.setParameter(null, "selected", selected);
            }

            var resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
            target.innerHTML = "";
            target.appendChild(resultDocument);
        }

        function displayResult() {
            var targetElement = document.getElementById("load");

            // code for IE
            if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                transformActiveX(xml, xsl, targetElement);
            }
            // code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
            else if (document.implementation && 
                     document.implementation.createDocument) {
                transformOther(xml, xsl, targetElement);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="displayResult()">
    <div id="load">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

i want to set click on leaf node when click on leaf node its text are set in my 
`<div id="result"/>` 
e.g:-
click on `One Day` its last child there have not child then its text copy in to `div` tag.

how its possible...
i think its work with jquery function click.
thanks...

Comment: that is not valid html

Comment: Putting punctuation at the end of each sentence in your question will make it much easier to understand. If you're not willing to make that effort, fewer people will be willing to make the effort to help.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to modify the HTML, Anyways try this:

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7xZTZ/1/)

```
$('li:not(:has(*))').click(function(){
     $('#result').text($(this).text());
});


<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the div to be outside of the list, not in de clicked node.

Answer (score 1):

This will select all li with no children. Then just attach click event. (assuming valid HTML)

```
$('li:not(:has(*))').click(.....)
```